# IDA pro crashes when trying to open a dos.ldw

Tags: ida

Whenever I try to load a malware executable in IDA pro 6.4 it crashes with message "IDA has encountered a problem".It creates a mini dump and exits. The malware file is shown as dos.lbw. Olly dbg is able to open and so is IDA pro version 5. Please help as to what should I do to resolve the issue

Comment: Open the malware executable in IDA 5, save the idc file, open the idc file in IDA 6? This should help you quickly. But apart from that, sending the malware file to Hex-Rays support, including your problem description, would probably be the best option.

Comment: Can you post a link to the binary sample please?

Comment: Try v6.6.  It contains bugfixes for PE files with certain properties.